# Combine if statement

Tags: php

I am basicly trying to combine these two if statements in to one. 
I want to be able to send the mail if both or either statements are true else dont send.

Mysearches >>

```
$search1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM NND where dname like 'EXP%' and Bl = 1 ");
$search2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM NND where dname like 'EXP%' and Bl = 0");

$lb = $search1->num_rows;
$db = $search2->num_rows;
```

My if's

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows($search1) == 0) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
} else {
    (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
}

    if (mysqli_num_rows($search2) == 0) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
} else {
    (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
}
```

thank you all for looking

Comment: make sure if anyone answer is helpful to you then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
  if (mysqli_num_rows($search1) != 0 || mysqli_num_rows($search2) != 0) {
    (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers));    
   } else {
        echo ("There is nothing to send");
   }
```

OR you can use what @rawathemant said:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($search1) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($search2) == 0) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
   } else {
        (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers));    
   }
```

Both are same, according to De=Morgan's Law :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant which uses the sum of the row counts from the two queries:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($search1) + mysqli_num_rows($search2) == 0) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
}
else {
    (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
}
```

But I think a better approach would be to run a single MySQL query instead:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN dname Bl = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS search  -- keep track of result set
FROM NND
WHERE
    dname LIKE 'EXP%' AND Bl = IN (0, 1);
```

Then, you may just check the total rows from this single query to make your decision.  Note that this approach is also attractive from a latency point of view, because it only requires a single round trip to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code : -

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($search1) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($search2) == 0) {
    echo ("There is nothing to send");
} else {
    (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
}
```